# Append same text to many files using cat or echo?

Tags: io-redirection, cat, echo

How can I write the same content to many text files by using `cat` or `echo` in only one command?

For example I want to write "hello" to file1 and file2. I tried:

```
echo "hello" >> file1 file2
```

but it didn't work. How can I do it?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Use `tee` to read from standard input and write to standard output and files.

```
echo "hello" | tee -a file1 file2
```

`-a` is the short (and portable/standard) for GNU tee's `--append`

Comment: Thanks, can flip it around for heredoc: `tee -a aaa bbb ccc << EOF contents ... EOF`.