# Simplest solution for outputting to a range of files in the shell

Tags: shell-script

I can create a range of files, say for example:

```
touch file{A..Z}.txt
```

What then would be the simplest solution for directing output to this range?

For example: `echo 'hello, world'` to all files in range of `{A..Z}`.

Comment: See [Append same text to many files using cat or echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50089/append-same-text-to-many-files-using-cat-or-echo). Drop tee's `-a` switch to truncate (overwrite) rather than append.

Answer (score 10):

If you're using this command to create files:

```
touch file{A..Z}.txt
```

You can equally write the same text to them (and create them) using the same expansion:

```
echo hello, world | tee file{A..Z}.txt
```

The `tee` command will also write to *stdout*, so you'll get a copy written to your terminal too. Redirect that to `/dev/null` if you don't want it:

```
echo hello, world | tee file{A..Z}.txt >/dev/null
```

Run [`man tee`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tee.1.html) on your local system for information about the command. For example the `-a` flag will append the text to the set of files.

The expansion itself is performed by the shell, which is `bash` in many cases. See [`man bash`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) for details.

Answer (score 2):

In `zsh`:

```
echo new test > file{A..Z}.txt
```

That's assuming the `multios` option has not been disabled.

Effectively, when a fd is redirected several times for writing (with `>`, `>>`, `1<>`, `>!`, `>|` redirection operators but that also applies with `|`...) in `zsh`, `zsh` redirects it instead to a pipe, and at the other end of the pipe, there's a background zsh process that despatches the data to all the targets in a `tee`-like fashion.

If the `noclobber` option is on, and `fileK.txt` for instance already existed, the redirection is aborted and the command not run at the point of opening it, so `fileK.txt` will not be clobber, but `fileA.txt` to `fileJ.txt` will have be opened (and created with 0 size).

Note that all those files are opened concurrently, so, like with `tee`, you'll run into the limit on the number of open file descriptors if redirecting to too many files:

```
$ echo test > file{A..Z}{A..Z}{A..Z}.txt
zsh: multio failed for fd 3: too many open files
$ echo test | tee file{A..Z}{A..Z}{A..Z}.txt
tee: fileBNH.txt: Too many open files
tee: fileBNI.txt: Too many open files
tee: fileBNJ.txt: Too many open files
[...]
tee: fileZZZ.txt: Too many open files
test
```

Here, with a command like `echo` which hardly costs anything do run (less anyway than the overhead of creating pipes and shoving data through them that the `tee`-like behaviour entails), you could open, populate and close the files in series instead of in parallel and have `echo` write directly to the files:

```
for f (file{A..Z}.txt) echo new test > $f
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have already created your files and only want to append new text, you can use tee command with -a option:

```
echo "new text" | tee -a file{A..Z}.txt
```

To add contents of a file (e.g. file0) to your files:

```
<file0 tee -a file{A..Z}.txt
```